# Blackberry 10 phonegap build issue: Invalid CSK password: signing not verified

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

1 We had requested signin key for BlackBerry Z10 and we received 2 files named client-PBDT-XXXX.csj and client-RDK-XXXX.csj.

2 We used this command to get db and csk file from csj files:

> blackberry-signer -register -csjpin csj_pin -storepass 
>                      keystore_Password client-RDK-xxxxxx.csj client-PBDT-
>                         xxxxx.csj

3 We entered add key in phone gap build server, it required for us to enter the db and csk file and then ask for password.

4 When we try to build app it returns back with error: Error - Invalid CSK password: signing not verified:

5 We are 100% sure that password provided to us by csk is correct.

Thanks

Comment: Your last point 'We are 100% sure that password provided to us by csk is correct' What do you mean? csk doesn't supply any password. You probably have this right but just in case, whatever you are putting in as 'keystore_Password' above is exactly what you should put into the password field of the phonegap build add key.

Comment: We had followed (https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup.html) URL to create blackberry 10 build but we are getting same error “Invalid CSK password”.

Comment: This error simply means your getting your keystore password wrong. If the signing was successful, the keystore_password you entered in the command listed above should be set. This should be then entered upon building and signing the app. If you haven't already, I'd request new keys and make sure you take down exactly what you are entering for the keystore password during registration. If that's not the problem something's up with the phone gap build server. Your best bet is just to set up a blackberry environment on your own machine. It's fairly easy to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/117

When you apply for Balckberry signkeys, did you choose also choose to obtain signkeys 'For BlackBerry OS 7.x and Lower'? If not, you might need to fill up the form again and obtain Blackberry signkeys for OS7 and below.

[https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys...](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html)

At the moment we only have PhoneGap up to 2.2.0 version, which still lack support for Blackberry 10 and Playbook.

From:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/blackberry_signed_package_always_fails_with_invalid_csk_password
as posted on January 18 2013 17h40